# Path problems in php

Tags: php, path

I got file index.php that includes index.php file in admin folder

```
<?php require 'admin/index.php'; ?>
```

in admin folder index.php file is basically login form that imports 2 css files

```
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Login Form</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="Designer" content="PremiumPixels.com">
        <meta name="Author" content="$hekh@r d-Ziner, CSSJUNTION.com">

        <-- site layout -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/structure.css" />

    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="myForm" class="boxlogin" action="index.php" method="POST">
            <fieldset class="boxBody">
                <label>Email <span style="color:red;"><?php if(isset($errorMsg)) echo $errorMsg;?></span></label>
                <input name="email" type="text" tabindex="1" placeholder="root" required>
                <label><a href="" class="rLink" tabindex="5">Forget your password?</a>Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" tabindex="2" required>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="footer">
                <label><input type="checkbox" tabindex="3">Keep me logged in</label>
                <input type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Login" tabindex="4"/>
            </div>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I run index.php file, script includes admin/index.php file.
But links to css are broken because admin/index.php file was included 
in file with different path.

I could change .css files path to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="admin/css/structure.css" />
```

and that would fix the problem, but what if I want to call /admin/index.php script from another path.

Let's assume that "root folder" is not in root folder on sever, for example `/var/www/php/loginscript/`

What is the best solution for this situation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/structure.css" />
```

Note the added `/` in `hrefs`

Answer (score 0):

I would create every static content an absolute URL (like: /css/reset.css) and set up a  tag in HTML.